# Использование EXISTS в запросе

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени. Есть задача - найти все отделы в которых нет сотрудников
Вот сам запрос

```
SELECT *
  FROM depts
 WHERE depts_id NOT IN (SELECT depts_id
                               FROM employees
                              WHERE depts_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать тоже самое но через EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.*
FROM depts D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees E WHERE E.depts_id = D.depts_id);
```

Comment: Спасибочки большое